# Cloudformation DeletionPolicy and UpdateReplacePolicy: does it cause an interrupt?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

I cannot find anywhere, but does adding DeletionPolicy and UpdateReplacePolicy on a Dynamodb Table cause any interruption/disruption on operations?

Comment: Why not try on some dummy table and test? Then you can update us with your findings.

Comment: @Marcin That's hard to test. I'd have to setup some sort of load to see if it affects the operations anyhow. Or you have a different idea?